# If matrices $B$ and $AB$ have the same rank, show that they have the same null spaces.

Tags: linear-algebra

Not sure how to do this one. A rather big hint was given, but I can't figure out how to actually do the second half of the hint:

> First show that $null(B)\subseteq null(AB)$, then  use the rank+nullity theorem.

So I figure I got the first part done:

\begin{align}
\vec{x}\in null(B)&\Longrightarrow B\vec{x}=\vec{0}\\
&\Longrightarrow A(B\vec{x})=\vec{0}\\
&\Longrightarrow (AB)\vec{x}=\vec{0}\\
&\Longrightarrow \vec{x}\in null(AB)\\
&\Longrightarrow null(B)\subseteq null(AB)
\end{align}

Not certain how to proceed from here... Any tips would be great.

Comment: This is **not** correct: $Bx = 0 \iff A(Bx) = 0$. It should be $Bx = 0 \implies A(Bx) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense.

Comment: Now, what does rank+nullity theorem say about $B$? Combined with the fact that $B$ and $AB$ have the same rank, what does this tell you about the nullity of $AB$?

Comment: You should have other hypotheses on the matrices $A$ and $B$. Are they square?

Comment: @egreg Sadly, no. This is all I was given.

Comment: @VedranŠego Does my proposed solution work? Or am I missing some step in between?

Comment: @agent154 Sorry for not replying; these days my network access is faulty at best. The current version seems fine to me. I glad you made it work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the suggestions of Vedran, I think the following might be a solution:

---

If $\vec{x}$ is in the null space of $B$, then:
\begin{align}
\vec{x}\in null(B)&\Longrightarrow B\vec{x}=\vec{0}\\
&\Longrightarrow A(B\vec{x})=\vec{0}\\
&\Longrightarrow(AB)\vec{x}=\vec{0}\\
&\Longrightarrow\vec{x}\in null(AB)\\
&\Longrightarrow null(B)\subseteq null(AB)
\end{align}

Since $null(B)$ is a subspace of $null(AB)$, we can conclude that the nullity of $B$ is less than or equal to the nullity of $AB$.

$A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix while $B$ is an $n\times p$ matrix, $AB$ is an $m\times p$ matrix. Therefore, $B$ and $AB$ both have the same number of columns. Let $p$ equal the number of columns in both $B$ and $AB$.

Let $k$ equal the rank of both $B$ and $AB$. Let $l$ equal the nullity of $B$ and $o$ equal the nullity of $AB$. Given that $B$ and $AB$ have the same number of columns:
\begin{align*}
k+l&=p\\
k+o&=p\\
l&=o
\end{align*}
Therefore, the nullity of $B$ is equal to the nullity of $AB$, and we can then conclude that $null(B)=null(AB)$. $\square$

Comment: Close, but not quite. The rank doesn't refer to the nullspace of a matrix.

Comment: @john Hmm.. Yes. I should have said that the nullity of $B$ is less than or equal to the nullity of $AB$. But I can't figure out how to combine that with the rank now, given that I don't know what the sizes of $B$ and $AB$ are. I don't know if they have the same number of columns or not.

Comment: Think through the matrix multiplication. Suppose that $B$ is an $n\times m$ matrix. What are the conditions on $A$ for the matrix product $AB$ to exist? What will be dimensions of $AB$?

Comment: @john I think I have it now...

Comment: Excellent! You could probably stand to improve your writing a bit (not a trivial statement, though this often comes with experience) but the important parts of the proof are all there.

Comment: @john How would you write it "properly"? I'd like to learn the proper way to word proofs, as I am planning to major, and possibly do a masters in Pure Math and Computer Science.

Comment: Well that's a rather big question. The important thing about proofs is that they flow in a nice logical order, with every step justified (unless you feel it doesn't need to be) and nothing assumed (unless clearly on purpose). For instance the line $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix while $B$ is an $n\times p$ matrix seems nice enough and I certainly know what you mean by it but nonetheless you are assuming information you don't have.

Comment: Rather this should probably go something like "Suppose $B$ is an $n\times p$ matrix. Then in order for the matrix product $AB$ to exist, $A$ must be some $m\times n$ matrix." In this paragraph, you also end with "Let $p$ equal the number of columns in both $B$ and $AB$" but you have already shown this, it's not something you're introducing now. These are small issues and may seem very much like nitpicking but they are actually somewhat important, especially in a field as disciplined as pure mathematics.

Comment: My advice is generally to read through a proof and try to question it at every step- are you really justified in saying that? where did that piece of information come from? Even your conclusion could probably use a bit of expansion in this case (though technically does suffice). This is your big finish but by itself it doesn't seem to fully resolve the issue. Why do the two nullities being equal mean the nullspaces are equal? Yes, the answer is embedded in the rest of the proof but personally (and this is a bit subjective) I feel it would benefit from being made explicitly clear.

Comment: Again, a lot of this comes from experience. I would recommend paying close attention to how your lecturers write their proofs as usually this should be a good structure to replicate. I hope that was helpful. Glad to hear you plan on studying more pure mathematics!

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $A$ is $m\times n$ and $B$ is $n\times p$. What you know from the rank-nullity theorem is that
\begin{gather}
\operatorname{rk}(AB)+\operatorname{nl}(AB)=p\\
\operatorname{rk}(B)+\operatorname{nl}(B)=p
\end{gather}
(where $\operatorname{nl}(X)$ denotes the dimension of $\operatorname{null}(X)$).
You also know that $\operatorname{null}(B)\subseteq\operatorname{null}(AB)$, because $x\in\operatorname{null}(B)$ means $Bx=0$, so that also $ABx=0$.

Subtract the equalities above, to get …

If $U_1\subseteq U_2$ are subspaces of $V$ and their dimensions …, then $U_1=U_2$.

(Fill in the blanks)

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

The rank-nullity theorem tells us that

rank + nullity = no. of columns.

How do the number of columns of $B$ and $AB$ compare? (or do we not know?)

Can we use this to find the nullity of $B$ and/or $AB$?

How does the nullity relate to the nullspace?

.

That should hopefully be quite a lot to go on.